# Search across multiple fields using one search box in Access

Tags: ms-access, search

I'm having a bit of trouble with my multiple field search form. I am wanting to search through multiple columns in my table but only using one search box.

I'm working in Design View with my query and search form and don't know squat about SQL so if you could tell me how to do this in design view that would be great.

Here's what I have: Table data-

[image]

**Search form**

[image]

So what I want to do is be able to search through all of the Instrumentalist columns while excluding any other columns (Song title, etc) but only using one search box to search for the entries in those instrumentalist columns.

All the other search boxes only search through their respective columns (Song title search box searches in the "song title" column, etc). Right now, the Instrumentalist search box only searches through the column labeled "Instrumentalist 1". I don't know if I need to change the properties of the "Instrumentalist" search box in the search form, or change something in the query.

In the query, I'm using `Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist 1] & "*"` for the Instrumentalist box.

Properties for this box are as follows:

Name: Instrumentalist 1

Control Source is blank.

Format is blank.

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: So, you want to enter `text` in `Instrumentalist search box` ans search that text to all columns heading have Instrumentalist, like `Instrumentalist1`, `Instrumentalist2` `Instrumentalist3`  bla bla

Comment: @harun24hr : yes, that is correct.

Comment: Can you share a sample file?

Comment: @harun24hr [Music Library Database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B84WlZVCOUxxYjZIRTBQeGotczg)

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is flawed - everything where you have an unknown number of entries should not be columns but rows.

There should be a separate table "Instrumentalists", with a one-to-many relationship from "Songs".

If you cannot possibly change your design, you can use `OR`.

```
... WHERE ([Instrumentalist 1] Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist 1] & "*" 
        OR [Instrumentalist 2] Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist 1] & "*" 
        OR [Instrumentalist 3] Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist 1] & "*")
```

But as you can see, it becomes rather horrible if you have many columns.

Comment: I created a separate table for "Instrumentalists", and made the relationship one-to-many from a "Songs" table. They are linked by the Song Title field. In the query design, for all the Instrumentalist fields, I am using `Like "*" & [Forms]![SearchForm]![Instrumentalist1] & "*"`, and again, all the other search boxes are working except for the Instrumentalist search box. The query results come up empty, even if all the fields in both tables have text in them.

Answer (score 0):

download the file from below link. It should work for you.

[File Download Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUqUZQzUv2td2xNR3FiSlUtb1k/view?usp=sharing)

**Note:** `In table no field can't be empty. At least you have to set default value or entry * (star) or any other value. Otherwise query will not work properly.`

Comment: I tried it out and it still didn't work. For example, in your portion that you made, in the search box for Instrumentalist, I typed in Delbert McClinton, which is one of the instrumentalists in the Instrumentalist2 field. When I ran the query, nothing came up.

Comment: But I tried just now and it shows 1 record. I don't know why it is not working to you.

Comment: Is it case sensitive?

Comment: May be not. Just I copy from table and paste into `Instrumentalist 1` text box.